# Values from CSV-file not seen as integers

Tags: php

I am extracting values from a CSV-file. The field `$data[8]` has the value `75332633`. When using the value in a SOAP call, I get an error saying that the value is not an Integer.

The I convert it using `intval($data[8])`. Then the value is `0`.

What could be wrong? Do you need more code?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($data[8]);` to see if it really is the value that you believe

Comment: Try casting it (int)$data[8]

Comment: @StrahinjaDjurić wouldn't that achieve the same as using `intval`?

Comment: @Robbie Averill Just told him to try its alternative, but yes, it is the same

Comment: var_dump($data[8]) gives this: string(17) "75332633"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are cheking wrong columnt because cast to integer is working fine:

```
echo var_export(intval('75332633'), 1) . PHP_EOL;

75332633
```

Comment: If i print out the value I get 75332633. If I use var_dump($data[8]) I get this: string(17) "75332633"

It is the right column, but something wrong anyway.

Comment: Could you try echo var_export(intval("75332633"), 1); ? What do you see?